# Calculate freight total in a computed field on Invoice - Odoo

Tags: sum, odoo, invoice, odoo-12, computed-field

I am trying to get a freight total to show on the bottom of my invoices. I created a new field in the Accounting Module called "Freight Total" (x_studio_freight_total). I want to get the sum of the "Subtotal" (price_subtotal) for any instance where the "Product" (product_id) = "FREIGHT".

For the field, x_studio_freight_total, I set the Dependencies as: "invoice_line_ids.price_subtotal, invoice_line_ids.product_id"

I set the Compute property as:

```
for record in self:
  if(record.invoice_line_ids.product_id == "FREIGHT):
    record['x_studio_freight_total'] = sum(record.invoice_line_ids.price_subtotal)
```

If an invoice shows a line with a 'Product' named "FREIGHT", and a 'Subtotal' of "12.75" I expect my 'Freight Total' field to display "12.75".

If an invoice has two lines with 'Product' named "FREIGHT, one with a 'Subtotal' of "12.75" and the other with a 'Subtotal' of "7.50", I expect the 'Freight Total' field to display "20.25".
But it currently is not displaying anything just "0.00"

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code

```
for record in self:
 record['x_studio_freight_total'] = 0
 for line in record.invoice_line_ids:
     if(line.product_id.name == "FREIGHT): #product_id.name to search product name
         record['x_studio_freight_total'] += line.price_subtotal`
```

Comment: I noticed a few errors in your code, but got the idea of what you were trying to do, unfortunately it is still returning 0.00 as my value.

Comment: you can use python debugger to check values if you're using pycharm add breakpoint to check the values or use raise Usererror to check your condition is working or not.